# Powershell: get-childitem searching in wrong directory

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm having an issue with a device that is supposed to save files on a file share, currently it's not working but I'm able to access a shared file-share on said device remotely. I created a script to automatically move the files on this file share, its scheduled to run every 5 mins.
The script:

```
$cnt=4;
$connected=$false;
while($cnt -gt 0) {
    if(Test-Connection 192.168.1.199 -Quiet) {
        if(!$connected) {
            New-PSDrive -Name "Q" -Root "\\192.168.1.199\shared" -PSProvider "FileSystem"
        }
        get-childitem -Path "Q:\" -Recurse | foreach-object { 
            $a=$_;   
            move-item -Path $a.FullName -Destination "C:\Server_Files";
            remove-item -Path $a.FullName;
        }
        $connected=$true;
    }
    else {
        if($connected) {
            Get-PSDrive Q | Remove-PSDrive
        }
        $connected=$false;
    }
    start-sleep -Seconds 60
    $cnt--;
}
if($connected) {
    Get-PSDrive Q | Remove-PSDrive
}
```

When I run this it doesn't show an error but instead moves files in the script's local directory to C:\Server_Files instead of from the shared folder. I don't understand why it would do it instead of giving an error if New-PSDrive failed.
the remove-item is because I notice with shared drives move-item doesnt usually delete the original file.

I can access the shared folder with file explorer and move/delete files from the share with no problem.
The destination is a folder on a domain-joined server if that matters.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

TL;DR:
when script is run, was expecting a mapped drive to result and script to move files from that mapped drive to a local folder on the C: drive, instead it moves files from the script current directory.

Comment: Add `-whatif` to move and delete oommands to see actual paths being used.

Comment: I doubt if "drive letters" are needed. What is the result of the command `Get-ChildItem -Path '\\192.168.1.199\shared'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rather interesting problem...

Per the documentation for Move-Item it will move entire directory trees in a single command.

However, as in this case where you're trying to move the **root directory** of the **PSDrive Q**. This causes problems. Although the move is accomplished it also automatically **removes the PSDrive Q** causing the subsequent Remove-PSDrive command to fail.

However, if you move a directory below the root of the PSDrive it works perfectly.

I setup the following directory on my NAS:
**CMShared\NAS-Downloads\MoveTest**
Then I copied some directories with files into it. The following code will move the entire MoveTest directory to my G: Drive under Test\MoveTest

```
Clear-Host
$SrvIP = "192.168.1.3"
$RootDir = "CMShared\NAS-Downloads"
$FromDir = "MoveTest"
$cnt=4

while($cnt -gt 0) {

    if(Test-Connection $SrvIP -Quiet) {

        if(-not (Test-Path "\\$SrvIP\$RootDir") -or
           -not (Test-Path "Q")) {
            $NPSDArgs = @{Name = "Q" 
                          Root = "\\$SrvIP\$RootDir"
                          PSProvider ="FileSystem"}
           $Null = New-PSDrive @NPSDArgs
        }

           Move-Item -Path "Q:\$FromDir" -Destination "G:\Test\$FromDir"

        Remove-PSDrive Q -Force
      
        Exit

    } #End if(Test-Connection

    $cnt--
    "$cnt try(s) remaining"

    start-sleep -Seconds 60
}

"Could Not connect to Server."
```

Of course if you want to "*Move*" the root directory of the PSDrive you have an issue I don't know how to solve.

Comment: I used a slightly modified version of your solution and it worked. I think my problem was I didnt realize I was attempting to move the drive itself, I thought I was just moving the contents lol. I accepted your answer. I cant upvote and I dont have enough karma. I appreciate the help